# How to efficiently set up an optional unidirectional OneToOne relationship using Hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate

Imagine the following scenario:
Two entities A and B. They are in an optional one-to-one relationship, which means an A can (but must not) have a B. The relation should (but must not) be unidirectional because I only ever need to go from A to B, but not vice versa. A is the parent and B is the child, so to speak.

Goal: When querying for an instance of A (which involves loading a potentially associated instance of B also), I want exactly one query to take place - left joining table A with table B would probably be the obvious way of achieving this.

I've literally went through dozens of Stackoverflow threads but none of them really adressed my problem to 100%. No matter how I design the tables/entity classes, Hibernate will always generate two queries, one for A first, and then one for B.

Design-wise, I am flexible, so I don't care whether A or B holds the join column, whether both tables have their own primary keys or whether it is a shared one, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are flexible design-wise, then you should use a FK column on `A`, as nullability can then be determined by looking at the FK column and Hibernate does not have to always emit a join.

> Goal: When querying for an instance of A (which involves loading a potentially associated instance of B also), I want exactly one query to take place - left joining table A with table B would probably be the obvious way of achieving this.

You have two options here.

Make the mapping EAGER `@OneToOne(fetch = EAGER)`, which will cause a join to happen when loading by id i.e. `entityManager.find`. If you want a join to happen when using a query/criteria you should use `fetch = LAZY` and make use of the second option.

Use a load graph entity graph (also see [the Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-entity-graph)). With this, you can specify per query, which parts of the entity model you want to load.